# Quickly tutorial section 4 will be availabe?

Tags: ppa, quickly

1. quickly tutorial
2. read to the end
3. Now that I have my package

Now that you have a package
Now that you've packaged your application, you can share the .deb file. However, if your users install your application this way, and you update the application, your users will have to find this out and reinstall the newer version themselves. This hassle can be avoided in Ubuntu by using Personal Package Archives (or PPAs). **Distrubuting your applications in this manner is covered in section 4 (not yet available).**

Can someone help me to bring my package to my ppa?

There is "Get Started" but no "Get Finished" in this tutorial. :(

I've 
created pgp, ssh keys
signed code of conduct
created ppa

dput doesn't work for me

Comment: How to use the ppa system is covered here - https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Of course ppa works. What part or step did you have a problem with ?

Comment: I don't realy remember now what warning I got. Something not signed or so.

Comment: hard to help without more information.

Comment: I found out that using dput is not the best way. Cause the package is not signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Project in Launchpad
2. Upload the code to Launchpad
3. Create your ppa

Then here is the right place where to proceed:

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted

This tutorial as video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bG-SXNX9Ww